# JavaScript rollover image gallery not working in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set up a small image gallery that functions with JavaScript Rollovers.  I have also added a bit of jquery to augment the images.  My problem is that everything works perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE or Chrome.  Everything will display in IE and Chrome, but when you click on a thumbnail, the large image won't populate.

Current page code:

```
<a href="#" onmouseup = "window.document.gallery.src = 'images/Gallery/Landscapes_Album/slides/Tern Lake Sunset.jpg'">
<img src="images/Gallery/Landscapes_Album/thumbs/Tern Lake Sunset.jpg" width="80" height="80" class="gallery-thumb" id="In"/></a>
```

Current jquery code:

```
// jQuery fade-in and fade-out

$(function() {
  // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 50%
  $(".gallery-thumb").css("opacity","0.5");

  // ON MOUSE OVER
  $(".gallery-thumb").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 100%
    $(this).stop().animate({
       opacity: 1.0
      }, "slow");
    },

    // ON MOUSE OUT
    function () {

    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
    $(this).stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Any errors reported in the JavaScript console of the non-working browsers?

Comment: what element is `window.document.gallery`? And why not use jQuery to bind the click event and select the element, or at least use `getElementById`? If the above code is exactly what you are running, I'm not sure how the click works on any browser.

Answer (score 0):

The error in chrome is "cannot set attribute src of undefined".  This is because the expression `window.document.gallery` does not evaluate to anything.  As MrOBrian noted, I do not see how this works in any browser.

An alternative implementation of the html could be:

```
<a href="#" onmouseup="$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'yourimage.jpg')">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" width="80" height="80" class="gallery-thumb" id="In"/></a>​
```

...although it would be more standard if you were just to do it somewhere in your javascript:

```
$(".gallery-thumb").parent().mouseup(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'yourimage.jpg');
});
```

I setup a jsFiddle for you to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfkeU/10/

Answer (score 0):

use css for this effect:

```
<a href="#">
<img class="img1" .../>
<img class="img2" .../>
</a>
```

the css:

```
a{position:relative;}
a img{position:absolute;top:T;left:L;}
a img.img1{ z-index:101;}
a img.img2{ z-index:100;}
a:hover img.img1{ display:none;}
```

is easier and cleaner ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I am relatively new to jQuery, and it took me a while to realize there was a simpler way to do this. I got everything working great now in all major browsers. I stopped using JavaScript and did the image swap with jQuery instead.